# WPF Image crossfade c#

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I have a list of images in my control

```
public List<BitmapImage> Images { get; set; }
```

I am using a timer to change the images.

```
        Image imgpanel = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        imgpanel.Source = image;
        imgpanel.Stretch = maintainAspectRatio ? Stretch.Uniform : Stretch.Fill;
        imgpanel.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
```

Does anyone know a way i can crossfade the images so they look better when swapping them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have two overlapping `Image` controls in the layout and use storyboards to fade them in/out. Then you could just load the image into the hidden `Image` control and when it's done, fade it in and the other one out. This goes on and on...

Comment: i will investigate thanks :) http://wpf-samples.blogspot.co.uk/2007/01/programmatic-fade-in-out-sample.html